# Windows 10 remote administration stopping

Tags: windows, remote, desktop

I have a windows 10 machine with remote administration enabled in my office. I used to connect to it for quite a while, and suddenly somewhere last summer it began to behave oddly.

I can access the machine for a while, after I reboot it. After I disconnect even minutes later I cannot connect again. The entire machine is working - if I go in the office I can use it. However I cannot connect to it from my home.

This really puzzles me - a reboot fixes the issue and I can connect again via remote desktop from my laptop at home.

Sure, I have a lot of software on it, including a company VPN, but this worked for years without issues. Starting the VPN client doesn't prevent me from using the remote desktop after that. It just refuses to accept any incoming connections after a while without any obvious reason... and rebooting the machine fixes the issue.

In my desperation I wrote a simple web application, to reboot my computer remotely and configured the local IIS to do that.

I did an experiment last weekend and kept the remote desktop open on my home computer  - no problems - it kept working for 3 days, but if I disconnect - I never know if I will be able to connect to it again. My Desktop computer runs windows 10 as well.

What causes this erratic behavior and how can I fix that?

Comment: does the service stop or are you just unable to connect? How are you connecting? via a vpn or direct port forward and is the port directly exposed to the internet?

Comment: The service service seems to be running, but I'm unable to connect. I'm connecting directly via IP & port